# Limit the amount of concurrent threads (with pthreads)

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, posix

I have to write a C application that posts info on web using CURL. The application must run up to N (let's say 10) requests in parallel at most. How can I wait for ANY thread to finish, rather than specific thread using `pthread_join()`.

I read about pthread_cond_wait, but most examples are how the control thread (main) wakes up a worker thread. I need just the opposite - worker threads must be able to signal/wakeup parent thread before exiting.

**Update:** Actually I need a way to make manager thread sleep and when a worker thread finishes it's job it should wake the manager thread to give it another job. It doesn't matter if the thread will end and new thread will be created for the job or thread pool will be used. Threre still needs to be a way to signal the manager that a job is finished.

**I hope that I DON'T get this suggestion**:

```
while(asleep){
  for(i = 0; i< threadCount; i++){
    pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
    if(threads[i] == IDLE_STATE)
      startNewJob();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
    usleep(100*1000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition variable are what you're after.  They can be used just as easily to signal the manager thread from the worker thread as vice-versa.

Your strawman example at the end is actually very similar to what you could do using a condition variable:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
while (!finished) {
  for(i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
    if(threads[i] == IDLE_STATE)
      startNewJob(i);
  }

  /* Not finished, and no idle threads, so wait */
  if (!finished)
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

When a thread is done, it would simply do:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
threads[self] = IDLE_STATE;
pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

Comment: So it is not a problem to signal using the same conditional variable from multiple threads? One thing bothers me. When I look at your code I see lock before the cycle. This means that when the thread tries to lock in order to signal it'll fail. Or does `pthread_cond_wait` release the lock?

Comment: I have another question. Is it possible to start a job outside the mutex lock? I want to make a function/method `waitForThreadToExit` which will return the thread id in the pool. so it will be `lock->cond_wait->unlock->if(idle)startNewJob`. Of course there will be only one thread that starts jobs. Or maybe it's a good idea to just make a function `void startNewThreadWhenPossible(Thread *)`

Comment: @NickSoft yes `pthread_cond_wait` unlocks the mutex while it's waiting.

Comment: @NickSoft: You can start a job outside the mutex lock, as long as only *one* thread is waiting for idle threads (as you say).  You can only read or write the `threads[]` array with the lock held, so that function will need to do something like `lock; cond_wait; set idle_thread based on threads[]; unlock; return idle_thread;`

Comment: can I run thread outside the mutex lock for pthread_cond_wait if more than one thread is waiting for idle threa IF I lock the same mutex before starting the thread

Comment: @NickSoft: No, because then you could have two threads try to start the same thread.

Comment: I just realized that it's not possible to run child threads from more than one manager thread because they will block each other unless others are in "pthread_cond_wait()" state. So control/manager thread should only be one. If other threads need to start a thread a queue could be used and the manager thread will pull threads from queue and start them (when there is free thread space). Am I going the right direction?

Comment: I guess it's a bit more complex because whoever pushes to queue will also have a limit (can't put thousands of jobs in queue) and it'll have to wait until queue has space for more. I'll try to format it as a question and update main question.

Comment: My recommendation is to use this solution, but think of the condition variable as a signal "there may be available threads to run on."  Any thread which does an action that might free up a thread should signal the variable.  Any thread which wishes to do something when a thread is free should wait for that condition.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than creating/destroying threads on demand, it'll be easier to create a pool of 10 worker threads on startup and have your main program feed jobs to them.

On startup, you'd create an array of 10 workers.  These might look something like

```
typedef struct worker
{
    pthread_t       thread;
    pthread_cond_t  cond;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    struct job*     job;
    int             quit;
} worker;
```

The manager would delegate jobs to each thread in turn by setting their `job` member then signalling the worker.

Each worker would loop until `quit` was non-zero, waiting on its condition being signalled.  After each signal it would read/process its `job` before reporting the results then waiting on its condition again.

**Edit:** You're not keen on thread pools.  You could instead try giving each thread a unique id; store some mapping between ids and other properties of each thread in the manager.  When each thread completes, have it add its id to a list owned by the manager then signal a condition in the manager.  Each time the manager wakes, it can pull the head from the list, lookup the appropriate thread, read back its job results then join the thread.  Note that the manager's list here will be accessed by multiple threads so reads/writes will need to be protected by a mutex.

**Edit2:** You'd like to know more about conditions and don't find the examples you've found helpful.  I'm not sure this'll be any better but here's [some code I've written](https://github.com/openhome/ohNet/blob/master/Os/Posix/Os.c).  The `OsSemaphore*` functions wrap conditions into a simple Wait/Signal API.

Comment: This is already a strategy in high performance servers like google for e.g. where there are thousands of requests and you cannot create a new thread/process for each child. At the same time, you cannot have a single thread/process catering all. So there is a pre-created pool of threads, and incoming requests are distributed among them. +1 for the pre created strategy which avoids overhead of new thread creation per request.

Comment: @fayyazkl Yes.  The pattern is useful in other places too; basically anywhere that risks having high/unbounded demand for transient use of a resource and needs to set a peak on resource usage.  I use it a lot in embedded programming to make memory demands more predictable and help guard against fragmentation.

Comment: That's a nice optimization that I will do when overhead of creating threads becomes problem. currently creating thread time will be 1/100 of the time to do thread's job, so I don't have to worry about it (yet). My question is more about the worker threads signalling the controller thread. How exactly should I do this? Can you give me a code example? Actually I want to know not when a thread is finished, but when a thread has done it's job. It doesn't matter if the thread will quit after that or it'll wait for another job. I want to wake up/signal main thread on this

Comment: @NickSoft I've updated my answer to include another option to have your threads signal completion.  Note that I think this risks being harder to code and test than a thread pool.

Comment: you didn't understand my comment. Pool or thread creation it's still the same. I need to signal control thread that job is finished so it assigns another job to the thread. And don't need explanation that much. I need code example. I'm new to pthreads and I don't know how to work with conditions.

Comment: @NickSoft Not sure if it'll help but I've updated my answer with a link to some code I've written using conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You want a condition variable, the same functions you have been looking at, but just turned around. The condition you are waiting for is "a worker thread has finished some work".

the main thread does:

- lock mutex
- while no thread has finished: pthread_cond_wait
- unlock mutex
- schedule work
- loop

Each worker thread, when it finishes work does:

- lock mutex
- mark completed
- pthread_cond_signal
- unlock mutex
- exit or wait for work

Comment: Are you sure that `schedule work` is safe to be outside the lock? In the example by `caf` it's done while locked.

Comment: @NickSoft - depends on the shared state etc, as long as you check there are no finished threads inside the mutex before waiting I think you'll be ok.